Intellij could not find or load main com/intellij/idea/Main
I just switched the JDK version folling the steps that IntelliJ gives https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html
The problem is that now IntelliJ won't open. Instead, it just displays a pop-up error saying:
Could not find or load main com/intellij/idea/Main

Because of this, I can't open IntelliJ. I know that JetBrains says "Do not change it unless you were specifically asked to do so by JetBrains support" but...
They suggested reinstalling IntelliJ, but I can't do that because it's not my computer.

To change it, just go to:
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC202X.X

Then, there is a file called idea64.exe.jdk, just open in a notepad and change the JDK version to the correct one and it will run
